# FactoryGirl has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, has-many

I have the following error when trying to use FactoryGirl to create a flight with `p = FactoryGirl.create(:flight)`:

```
 ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey:
   PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  insert or update on table "flights" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_11f6e1e673"
   DETAIL:  Key (customer_id)=(457) is not present in table "customers".
   : INSERT INTO "flights" ("flight_type", "route", "customer_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"
```

My model is as below :

*flight.rb*

```
 belongs_to :customer
```

*customer.rb*

```
has_many :flights
```

And here is what I have in Factories.rb :

```
factory :customer do
     customer_name 'Customertest'
     contract_type 'true'   
end

factory :flight do
    flight_type 'Medivac'
    route 'A - B - C - A'
    customer
end
```

Do you see why it is not working ?

Thanks

Comment: so what you want to do is when you create a **flight** its associated with a **customer**

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you are looking looks more like this

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :flight do
    flight_type { 'Medivac' }
    route { 'A - B - C - A' }
    after(:create) do |flight|
      flight.customer ||= Customer.last || FacoryGril.create(:customer)
    end
  end
end
```

you can see this code working from this sample app https://github.com/mzaragoza/sample_factorygirl_with_has_many_association

Comment: Thanks for the reply but when I try I get the following error now Failure/Error: p = FactoryGirl.create(:flight)
     
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "customer_id" violates not-null constraint
       : INSERT INTO "flights" ("flight_type", "route", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"

Comment: We all started at the same point. I am just trying to make my teacher  proud